# IntelliJ Plugin Development: how to make class extend another class

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide, intellij-plugin

I'm implementing a plugin in which I need to add `extends` clause for an existing class.

I have `PsiClass` instance representing say `MyClass`.

There is an API that allows to get all the classes that `MyClass` extends:

```
PsiReferenceList extendsList = psiClass.getExtendsList()
```

And theoretically I can add something to it and that will work.

**Problem:** `PsiReferenceList.add()` consumes `PsiElement` and I don't know how to create an object of `PsiElement` having fully qualified name of the class I want to use.

More specifically, how to transform string `com.mycompany.MyAbstractClass` to `PsiElement` representing this class?

**Update:**
I managed to achieve the result using the following logic:

```
PsiElementFactory factory = JavaPsiFacade.getInstance(project).getElementFactory();
PsiReferenceList extendsList = aClass.getExtendsList();
PsiShortNamesCache instance = PsiShortNamesCache.getInstance(project);
PsiClass[] abstractClasses = instance.getClassesByName(
        "MyAbstractClass", 
        GlobalSearchScope.allScope(project)
);
PsiJavaCodeReferenceElement referenceElement = factory
        .createClassReferenceElement(abstractClasses[0]);
extendsList.add(referenceElement);
```

It works but I guess there should be more optimal way.

Comment: The best place to ask IntelliJ IDEA API questions is the [development forum](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/topics/200366979-IntelliJ-IDEA-Open-API-and-Plugin-Development).

Answer (score 1):

You can make a `String` which is the code you want to generate, like

```
String code = "class A extends B { }"
```

Then, use this code to convert text into `PsiElement`:

```
PsiElement fromText(String code, Project project) {
  return PsiFileFactory
        .getInstance(project)
        .createFileFromText(JavaLanguage.INSTANCE, code)
        .getFirstChild()
}
```

And you'll get the corresponding `PsiElement`.

Then, `myClass.replace(fromText(code))`.

BTW you can also do `classNamePsiElement.addAfter(fromText("extends Xxx"))` which is considered more efficient.

Comment: The class I'm changing is already defined, I can't replace it's content. I literally need to add `extends MyAbstractClass` between the class name and it's body.

Comment: I don't know what do you mean by "it's already defined so I can't replace the content", but if you don't want to replace, you can`element.addAfter()`, and pass the PsiElement that corresponds to `extends Xxx`.

Comment: What is `classNamePsiElement `? Could you also take a look on my update, probably it would help to understand the context.